# No grub menu at boot

Tags: grub2

I cannot get a grub menu. Holding/pressing <kbd>shift</kbd> yields `GRUB loading` but then it just boots as normal. I have edited `/etc/default/grub` correctly (`HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` commented out and `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10`) I have also tried with <kbd>escape</kbd> but nothing happens. I have tried Boot Repair already but it also did not help.

Comment: You can try to set this option `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=countdown` to explicitly tell grub to show the countdown counter : https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Simple-configuration.html

Comment: Have you tried to enter BIOS or try different keyboard type? Is your keyboard working at grub boot time?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
nano  /etc/default/grub
```

In the open file these lines are usually shown

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

You should leave them like this:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=15
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> Save file  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> Close nano

Continue running:

```
update-grub
```

You when restarting should see the grub menu

Comment: My grub file was already set up like that, but I copy pasted your version and updated grub but still no GRUB at boot

Answer (score 1):

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=15

GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

With **grub version 2.04**, this config in `/etc/default/grub` gives me a grub menu with a 15sec countdown displayed at the bottom.

After the 15secs is up, it boots the first item (the zeroeth, actually) automatically.

( `grub-install --version` will tell you the version of your grub)

Also, to make your changes take effect, don't forget to run `sudo update-grub` after being done with editing.