# How to bring up grup boot menu in my acer laptop?

Tags: grub2, acer, grub-efi, 18.04

I'm new to this forum and Ubuntu.
I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my Acer E5. When Ubuntu boots up it directly boots. There is no grub menu. How do I bring it up?

Comment: Maybe your UEFI boot option is pointed straight at Ubuntu instead of GRUB? I'm not sure if that's even possible, but I've seen similar things with Windows. Are you using UEFI or BIOS?

Comment: Related: [No grub menu at boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/850486/no-grub-menu-at-boot), [No Grub Menu after installing Ubuntu 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974180/no-grub-menu-after-installing-ubuntu-17-04), [Why is Grub menu not shown when starting my computer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182248/why-is-grub-menu-not-shown-when-starting-my-computer)

Comment: Yes I'm using **UEFI**.  When Ubuntu installation my laptop is not boots up, so I use this link as guide. (https://itsfoss.com/no-bootable-device-found-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 2):

You can gain access to a more detailed menu by holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key while you're booting.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this and how I fixed it was this:

Main -> Network Boot -> F12 Boot Menu: [Enabled]

Save & exit

On next startup, hit F12, and I was presented with Windows or Ubuntu.  Selected Ubuntu and it started right up.